Glacier API: "Only the owner can operate insertOne()" error when creating NFTs
To effectively bring your query to a community, it's essential to be clear and concise while providing enough technical context. Here's how you can frame your question:

Subject/Title:
"Error: 'Only the owner can operate insertOne()' in Glacier Network NFT Metadata Storage"

Body:
Hi everyone! 
I'm working on an NFT project where I've integrated the Glacier Network to store the metadata for each NFT. While testing, I encountered an issue:

What I'm Doing:
I created a dataset for storing NFT metadata when minting my first NFT.
Later, I tried creating NFTs from other accounts and storing their metadata in the same dataset.

The Issue:
It's throwing an error:
"only the owner can operate insertOne()"

What I Need Help With:

Is it possible to allow multiple accounts to write to the same dataset?
How can I resolve this error to enable other accounts to store metadata?



Here’s a snippet of my setup:
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { GlacierClient } from "@glacier-network/client";
import { useAccount } from "wagmi";

const useGlacierService = () => {
  const [client, setClient] = useState(null);
  const endpoint = "https://web3storage.onebitdev.com/glacier-gateway";
  const address = useAccount()


  // INITIALISE CLIENT
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      if (typeof window !== "undefined" && window.ethereum) {
        const clientInit = new GlacierClient(endpoint, {
          provider: window.ethereum,
        });
        setClient(clientInit);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error initializing GlacierClient:", err);
    }
  }, [endpoint]);


  // CREATE NEW NAMESPACE
  const createNamespace = async (name) => {
    if (!client) return;
    try {
      return await client.createNamespace(name);
      //   console.log("Namespace created with ID:", newNamespace.insertedId);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error creating namespaceName:", error);
    }
  };

  // FETCH ALL NAMESPACES
  const fetchNamespaces = async () => {
    if (!client) return;
    try {
      // const address = process.env.WALLET_ADDRESS;
      return await client.namespaces(address);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching namespaces:", error);
    }
  };

  // ACCESS A SPECIFIC NAMESPACE
  const getNamespace = (name) => {
    return client.namespace(name);
  };

  // CREATE DATASETS
  const createDataset = async (namespaceName, datasetName) => {
    try {
      const namespace = client.namespace(namespaceName);
      return await namespace.createDataset(datasetName);
      //   console.log("Dataset created with ID:", newDataset.insertedId);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating dataset:", error);
    }
  };

  // Create a collection in a dataset
  const createCollection = async (
    namespaceName,
    datasetName,
    collectionName,
    schema
  ) => {
    try {
      const mynamespace = client.namespace(namespaceName);
      const mydataset = mynamespace.dataset(datasetName);

      const result = await mydataset.createCollection(collectionName, schema);
      console.log("Collection created successfully:", result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating collection:", error);
    }
  };

  // Insert data into a collection
  const insertData = async (
    namespaceName,
    datasetName,
    collectionName,
    data
  ) => {
    try {
      const namespace = client.namespace(namespaceName);
      const dataset = namespace.dataset(datasetName);
      const collection = dataset.collection(collectionName);
      return await collection.insertOne(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  // Update a specific record in a collection
  const updateOne = async (
    namespaceName,
    datasetName,
    collectionName,
    query,
    update
  ) => {
    try {
      const namespace = client.namespace(namespaceName);
      const dataset = namespace.dataset(datasetName);
      const collection = dataset.collection(collectionName);
      return await collection.updateOne(query, update);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };
  // Delete a specific record in a collection
  const deleteOne = async (
    namespaceName,
    datasetName,
    collectionName,
    query
  ) => {
    try {
      const namespace = client.namespace(namespaceName);
      const dataset = namespace.dataset(datasetName);
      const collection = dataset.collection(collectionName);
      return await collection.deleteOne(query);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  // Query a dataset
  const getDataset = async (namespaceName, datasetName) => {
    try {
      const namespace = client.namespace(namespaceName);
      const dataset = namespace.dataset(datasetName);
      return dataset;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  //Get a collection 
  const getCollection = async (namespaceName, datasetName, collectionName) => {
    try {
      const namespace = client.namespace(namespaceName);
      const dataset = namespace.dataset(datasetName);
      const collection = dataset.collection(collectionName)
      return collection;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  const getCollectionData = async (
    namespaceName,
    datasetName,
    collectionName,
    query
  ) => {
    if (!client) {
      console.error("Client not initialized");
      return null;
    }
    try {
      console.log("Client instance:", client);
      console.log("Namespace name:", namespaceName);
      const mynamespace = client.namespace(namespaceName);
      const mydataset = mynamespace.dataset(datasetName);
      const mycollection = mydataset.collection(collectionName);
      const data = await mycollection.find(query).toArray();
      return data;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error retrieving data", err);
    }
  };

  return {
    createNamespace,
    fetchNamespaces,
    getNamespace,
    createDataset,
    createCollection,
    insertData,
    updateOne,
    deleteOne,
    getDataset,
    getCollection,
    getCollectionData,
  };
};

export default useGlacierService;


If anyone has experience with Glacier Network or managing similar permissions for datasets, I’d really appreciate your insights.
Thank you in advance! 

